How to save material shading node into a library with bpy (how to export and import shading nodes)
Could someone tell me what are the bpy commands to save a shading node in a library? and how to recover it for another project within blender from this library?
@unwave
I'm talking about the nodes that we can create on the shader editor to create materials that we can then use on objects

which would make it possible to create libraries of this type:


Are you talking about a shading node group? The one from bpy.data.node_groups.

You don’t create single nodes, you add them. I think you mean how to save a node tree.

You don't save a single node, but node trees in the form of materials and nodes groups, which are the ID data blocks, using bpy.data.libraries.load and bpy.data.libraries.write.
If you need to save a single node then you need to find a way to serialize it to text, or you can use the node groups to store a single node.
